# Lightbox code works fine in Chrome/Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, joomla

I have added some code for a "lightbox" effect on one of my images (below) [The [website](http://www.actinic.co.uk/legal.html) is live], which opens a YouTube video.

[image: Lightbox Image]

The name of the plugin is called [YOOeffects](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/scripts/4533)

And this is the code for the setup.

```
<p>
    <span id="avrpopup_eBay Marketplace" title="{handler:'iframe',size:{x:1024,y:768},url:'index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_avreloaded%26view%3Dpopup%26Itemid%3D25%26divid%3DeBay+Marketplace'}"></span>
    <a href="#" onclick="AvrPopup(event, 'eBay Marketplace', 'lightbox');">
        <img alt="120top_tips" src="/images/stories/content-images/120top_tips.jpg" height="186" width="150">
    </a>
</p>
```

It worked for Chrome and firefox yet seems to expand and look deformed in IE.

Not really sure why, are there any specific fixes in Internet Explorer I need to apply?

Comment: Which version(s) of IE do you need this to work in?

Comment: Can you post your code to initialize this plugin?

Comment: Is the code in the question not enough?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try 'default' joomla's mechanizm of creating pop-up windows. 
It is very easy implement. To make it work just add this code into your template following code

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
```

and add class 'modal' to the link which should open popup window. 
http://www.jeepstone.co.uk/2009/03/06/open-content-in-a-modal-pop-up-in-joomla/
I hope this will help you. If no - sorry for wasting your time.

**UPD**

Your setup code differs from the one in [demo](http://www.yootheme.com/tools/free-stuff/yooeffects)

```
<a rel="ligthbox;width=405;height=340" title="1984 Apple's Macintosh Commercial" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/OYecfV3ubP8&amp;autoplay=1">YouTube</a>
```

Why you aren't using code from tutorial?
What does function `AvrPopup('....')` do?

Comment: I will test this out and see what i get

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the plugin supports IE ≤ 7, probably should, as the developer say so, but it seems like the problem lies in switching the IE to a different [document mode](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/19/internet-explorer-8-document-and-browser-modes/) (in the case of IE8) and at the same time using a javascript library – [**IE8.js**, claiming: "it makes IE behave like a standard-compliant browser"](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which appears not to be compatible with this plugin (or more precisely, the plugin doesn't count with this library). So to make it work, try to remove this conditional comment:

[Line 39]

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="/templates/actinic/js/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

or possibly remove this meta element (this should help to make it work at least under IE8):

[Line 5]

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
```